# Weird probability equation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to read a lines of code in C++ and I came cross this exponetial.

`exp(x * log(lambda) - lambda - lgamma(x + 1))`

x and lambda could mean anything, but I know it's trying to calculate the probability of something, just judging from the only comment made on this function.

I was thinking it might be related to the Poisson distribution, but after taking the taylor expansion of the Poisson distribution, I'm not sure what this equation is.
Maple gives me `exp(-lambda) + (exp(-lambda)*ln(lambda) + exp(-lambda)*gamma)*x` for the first two terms, which isnt really related.

Does anyone know what this is exponential is?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: $\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}\frac 1 {x!}$. The pmf of a poison distribution with $x=0,1,...$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do. First note that lgamma returns the natural logarithm of the gamma function evaluated at its argument.

Your equation is $e^{x\log \lambda-\lambda-\log \Gamma(x+1)}=\lambda^xe^-\lambda[\Gamma(x+1)]^{-1} =\lambda^xe^-\lambda\frac 1 {x!}$, the pmf of a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$ and support $x=0,1,2,..$.

So it’s calculating the probability of observing $x$ number of so and so in the context of your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved an undergrad's life today.